# How to reverse a string where all characters that are not a letter stay in the same place, and all letters reverse their position?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Suppose I have a string like `"t-hE-rEd=fiSh!!"`

I want to rearrange the string such that:

- non-letters remain in the same positions;
- letters are placed in the remaining positions, but reversed vis-a-vis the original string.

Thus, the desired output is
output: "h-Si-fdE=rEht!!"

How can I do this in Javascript?

Comment: Think about how you would describe how to do this if you did not have a computer.

Comment: I assume the best way would be to remove and store the special characters, reverse the string without the special characters, and then re-add the special characters.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```js
function revers(str){
    var letters = [];//array for letters
    var special = [];//array for other charactors

    for(var i = 0;i<str.length;i++){//loops througth str
     if(str[i].match(/[a-zA-Z]/)){//filter letters
      letters.push(str[i]);
     }else{
      special[i] = str[i];//adds special charactors in relative spot
     }
    }

    for(var i = 0;i<str.length;i++){
     if(special[i] == undefined){
      special[i] = letters[letters.length - 1];
      letters.pop();
     }//rverses position of letters
    }
     var fin = special.join('');//joins the array to a string
     return fin;//returns string
}

console.log(revers('a-bC-dEf=ghIj!!'));
```